# how to get the list after the delete the record?

Tags: dynamic-visualforce

I have an problem with my vf page,whenever I delete the record from my list ,record will deleted but I unable to return my list.

```
public PageReference deleteRecord()
{
   ID rid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ruleID');
   PageReference deletepage = new PageReference ('/'+rid+'/e?retURL=/apex/performanceReviewoutput');

   String runQuery='select  Name from Performance_Review_Input__c where id= \''+rid+'\''; 
   List<Performance_Review_Input__c> listdeDatabase.Query(runQuery);

   delete listdel;
   return deletepage;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to return to the edit page of a deleted record? What are you trying to accomplish?

Two things I notice about your code, you are vulnerable to [SOQL injection](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) and you don't even need to perform a query.

If you remove your query, you actually remove the injection vulnerability. Before performing the delete, however, I would do a little checking on the Id first.

```
if (ruleId instanceOf Id && Id.valueOf(ruleId).getSObjectType() == Performance_Review_Input__c.sObjectType)
{
    Performance_Review_Input__c recordToDelete = new Performance_Review_Input__c(Id=ruleId);
    delete recordToDelete;
}
```